# check string for youtube link or image

Tags: php

I have a small piece of code that checks a string for a url and adds the < a href> tag to create a link. I also have it check the string for a youtube link and then add rel="youtube" to the < a> tag.

How can I get the code to only add rel to the youtube links?

How can I get it to add a different rel to any type of image link?

```
$text = "http://site.com a site www.anothersite.com/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyxqmghxS6M here is another site";

$linkstring = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0">\4</a>', $text ); 
if(preg_match('/http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^&]+/', $linkstring, $vresult)) {
    $linkstring = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a rel="youtube" href="\0">\4</a>', $text ); 
          $type= 'youtube';
          }
else {
$type = 'none';
}
echo $text;
echo $linkstring, "<br />";
echo $type, "<br />";
```

Comment: How do you want to detect images?  You can use the file extension, or do a curl request and get the headers which will have the content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

**Code**:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyxqmghxS6M">Link</a>');
$html->find('a', 0)->rel = 'youtube';
echo $html;
```

**Output**:

```
[username@localhost dom]$ php dom.php
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyxqmghxS6M" rel="youtube">Link</a>
```

You can build an entire page DOM or a simple single link with this library.

Detecting hostname of URL:
Pass the url to parse_url.  parse_url returns an array of the URL parts.

**Code**:

```
print_r(parse_url('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyxqmghxS6M'));
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.youtube.com
    [path] => /watch
    [query] => v=UyxqmghxS6M
)
```

Comment: Yeah its not bad.  Similar to jquery's dom manipulations if your doing alot of ajax+php work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
//text
$text = "http://site.com/bounty.png a site www.anothersite.com/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyxqmghxS6M&featured=true here is another site";

//Youtube links
$pattern = "/(http:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-z0-9\-_\|]{11})[^\s]*/i";
$replacement = '<a rel="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\3">\0</a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);

//image links
$pattern = "/(http:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[^\/]+\/[^\s]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif)[^\s]*/i";
$replacement = '<a rel="image" href="\0">\0</a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

note that the latter can only detect links to images which have an extension. As such, links like www.example.com?image=3 will not be detected.